# Fetch records with CloudKit in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, records, cloudkit

i try to fetch records with CloudKit. I use the example from Apple.

I can save records but i can't get them..

Here's the code to fetch the records saved :

```
func fetchRecords(completionHandler: ((NSArray!) -> Void)!) {
    var predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    var query = CKQuery(recordType: "type", predicate: predicate)
    /*self.publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil, { (results:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    if (error){
    println("An error occured in \(NSStringFromSelector(__FUNCTION__)) \(error)");
    } else {
    completionHandler(results)
    }
    })*/

    var operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

    var results = NSMutableArray()

    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord!) -> Void in
        results.addObject(record)
    }

    operation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor:CKQueryCursor!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            if (error) {
                // Error Code 11 - Unknown Item: did not find required record type
                if (error.code == 11) {

                    // Since schema is missing, create the schema with demo records and return results

                }
                else {
                    // In your app, this error needs love and care.
                    println("An error occured in \(NSStringFromSelector(__FUNCTION__)): \(error)");
                    abort();
                }
            } else {
                completionHandler(results)
            }
        })
    }

    self.publicDatabase.addOperation(operation)
}
```

When i run this the "abort()" is called and i get this in the console :

An error occured in fetchRecords:

Thanks for helping guys.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to save?  Make sure the record types match.  You specify the record type as "type" above but not sure what you used when you saved.

Comment: Also, can you share the more detailed error message?  The message "An error occurred in fetchRecords" is just the string message, not the actual exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the way you are creating your predicate.  The column/attribute that you want to query on is not specified.

Instead of:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
```

you should do something along the lines of:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "someColumn == true")
```

Comment: Actually, `NSPredicate(value: true)` is the correct syntax in Swift to return all records.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
if (error)
```

with

```
if (error != nil)
```